# Eigenvectors corresponding to eigenvalues

Tags: r, pca, matrix-decomposition

In R, the eigen() returns descending sorted eigenvalues. However, the eigenvectors do not correspond to these sorted eigenvalues. How do I identify the eigenvector corresponding to the ith sorted eigenvalue?

One approach might be to sort by the norm of the eigenvectors (is there a procedure in R that can do this). I imagine there is a simple method I am missing.

Comment: "However, the eigenvectors do not correspond to these sorted eigenvalues" yes it does. "One approach might be to sort by the norm of the eigenvectors" hard, given that eigenvectors are *normed*

Comment: The following webpage suggested the vectors from eigen() were not sorted: http://tolstoy.newcastle.edu.au/R/help/03a/3713.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Look at the end of the `eigen` function:

```
...    
ord <- sort.list(Mod(z$values), decreasing = TRUE)
}
list(values = z$values[ord], vectors = if (!only.values) z$vectors[, 
      ord, drop = FALSE])}
```

That means both values and vectors are sorted by `ord`. So why eigenvectors ordering is not corresponding to the eigenvalues ordering?

Comment: It is also crucial to me since I use this for the extraction of static factors.